# How to return success info from script in PHP

Tags: php

I have a page that sends a form to a PHP script. I would like to somehow return success information to the page when the script executes. Now I can't use jQuery AJAX requests since my form submits files to the server and I would like to avoid appending get parameters to the url if possible.

I tried doing this:

```
$_REQUEST['status'] = 'File uploaded successfully';
```

But when I check whether this variable is set on my page, I get false.

What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: how are you getting $_REQUEST['status'] ???

Comment: $_REQUEST holds _incoming_ parameters. So if you are not using AJAX, then you send the form “normally”? Then the browser will try to _display_ the response, so it should be a normal HTML document.

Comment: use $_SESSION instead of $_REQUEST

Comment: @chiragode On the page that my script redirects to I do `if (isset($_REQUEST['status'])) echo $_REQUEST['status'];`

Comment: @Ganesh What I meant is that I do not want to append get parameters to the url that my script redirects to after executing.

Comment: @JanaBanana I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload this link shall help your case

Comment: How is the form sent ? Using action and POST ? If you can't use Ajax-style uploading how about having some kind of callback ? In short page calls script, script calls page. You could redirect using header. You could do a check using file_exists or something along those lines.

Comment: @JamesPoulson I'm already doing all of this, but how do you suggest I return the status?

Comment: @JanaBanana There is that possibility of doing a POST request using curl. Apache needs to be set up for it though so you need to check your phpinfo.

http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Comment: Or if you need to go back to the page then save the return. Either in a session variable or in a database. Note that the thing to recognize here is that HTTP is stateless ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you say `I would like to avoid appending get parameters to the url`. If that's your only concern, you can use [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), no query parameters whatsoever.

But if you explained it correctly, it's just a normal form posted to a normal php script. Isn' t it? In that case, just echo out the success/failure info:

```
$succes = do_something($_POST['my_posted_var']);
if($success) {
    echo 'Yeah! It worked!';
} else {
    echo 'This is disappointing...';
}
```

Or redirect the user to your thank you page.

```
header('Location: '. thanks.php);
```

**EDIT** Ok got it (see comment). In that case, use sessions. You can transfer data between requests without juggling with parameters of some sort. Please read [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Summarized you could do something like below:

```
=execution_script.php=
session_start();
// do your stuff
$_SESSION['status'] = 'succes'; // or failure for that matter
header('Location: status_view.php');
```

.

```
=status_view.php=
session_start();
echo 'Status: ' . $_SESSION['status'];
```

Comment: What I meant is that I do not want to append get parameters to the url that my script redirects to after executing. My script end in `header('Location: example.com/sth')` and on this url I want to know whether or not the script was executed successfully.

Comment: This looks like the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

1). you can rewrite url
like "index.php?msg=$success"
at your front page retrive this message by $_REQUEST['msg'].

2). you can use session flash messages that most of MVC frameworks are using try to google it abt it you will get more information about it

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this...try it

```
header('Location: welcome.php?status=File Uploaded Successfully..!!');.
```

and then display success message using

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['status'])) echo $_REQUEST['status'];
 header('Location: welcome.php');. ?>
```

or you can simply do this

```
header('Location: welcome.php?status=1');.
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['status']=='1')) echo 'File Uploaded Successfully..!!';
```

Comment: But this is exactly what I wrote that I would like to avoid. I want to read my status from $_REQUEST, but I don't want it visible in the URL.

Comment: then you can use javascript alert

Comment: Worst practise that I can think of.